# How to get a target's property value inside a control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

Suppose I have the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Grid>
      <Rectangle Width="100" Height="20" />
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="25" />
<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="50" />
<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="75" />
```

What do I need to do to the control template to have the rectangle be the width of the button instead of a hard-coded 100 each time? Is there a way for me to access the property value of my target type from inside of my control template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
 <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't specify `Width` or `Height` for `Rectangle` at all and let it stretch to the size of the `Button`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Grid>
      <Rectangle/>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```